# How to configure the default type of VM that gets allocated in AKS cluster

Tags: azure, azure-automation, azure-aks

How to configure the default type and number of VM that gets allocated in AKS cluster? Is there a way we can do this per Resource Group?

Why am I asking this? From the point of view of saving costs by default in non-prod environments and minimize human error in general to automate and streamline things as part of DevOps group.

Your solution-recipe is much appreciated.

Comment: I think you can use the Azure template to create AKS with default value in it. The template can be used multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

you can use powershell\az cli\arm template\sdk's to generate AKS. either way works. you can also use third party solutions like pulumi, ansible.

all of these solutions would allow you to pass in parameters to define vm size. you can restrict those with pre-validation

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/11616) one which has lot of information regarding your ask.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `az aks create`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/aks?view=azure-cli-latest#az-aks-create

The PowerShell equivalent `New-AzAks` is not as configurable but it does allow for the definition of the node count. You can always execute cli from PowerShell if you prefer to work with PowerShell in Automation.